# How to retrieve nested data from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the structure of data from my firebase:

[image: Structure of data in firebase]

I have problem to retrieve all "menukedai" data. By using the code below, data from "menukedai" didnt come out. For your information, the data of "menukedai" will come from the user.

This is my attempt:

```
foodDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads").child("menukedai");

foodDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            foodmenu foodmenu = postSnapshot.getValue(foodmenu.class);
            fooddata.add(foodmenu);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(foodlist.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

This is my foodmenu class.

```
package com.example.trialfoodbuddy;

public class foodmenu {
    private String Foodimage;
    private String Foodname;
    private CharSequence Foodprice;

    public foodmenu(){
        //empty constructor needed
    }
    public foodmenu(String foodimage, String foodname, CharSequence foodprice){
        Foodimage = foodimage;
        Foodname = foodname;
        Foodprice = foodprice;
    }

    public String getFoodimage(){
        return Foodimage;
    }

    public String getFoodname(){
        return Foodname;
    }

    public CharSequence getFoodprice(){
        return Foodprice;
    }

    public void setFoodimage(String foodimage){
        Foodimage = foodimage;
    }

    public void setFoodname(String foodname){
        Foodname = foodname;
    }

    public void setFoodprice(CharSequence foodprice){
        Foodprice = foodprice;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag. Also: the Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I will be more aware about the tag after this.

Answer (score 0):

I Believe you want to get the information nested under "menukedai" so you will need to add another loop for that information

```
foodDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
foodDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot uploadSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            // this is where you actually getting the information 
            for(DataSnapshot menuItemSnapshot : uploadSnapshot.child("menukedai").getChildren()){
                foodmenu foodmenu = menuItemSnapshot.getValue(foodmenu.class);
                fooddata.add(foodmenu);
            }
        }
    }
    // Log the values and check them to make sure you getting the data you want if always nice so I added it for you here
    Log.i("Values","My values are:"+foodmenu);
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(foodlist.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Normally speaking, You should always use the variable names in your class in your Database so when you pulling the information, your constructor would know what value assign to which variable in your class.

Comment: Thank you for your help and tips. I will improve the way i code my program. I still have question about this.

 What if i want the data from "menukedai", but it is based on the user id. For example if user click on first id, then all info from "menukedai" under that user id will come out.

Comment: You'd attach the listener to `foodDatabaseRef.child(uid).addValueEventListener(...` in that case, remove the `for(DataSnapshot menuItemSnapshot` loop, and then `menuItemSnapshot.child("menukedai").getValue(foodmenu.class)` in that case.

Comment: is it like this?

 `
foodDatabaseRef.child(userid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot uploadSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    uploadSnapshot.child("menukedai").getValue(foodmenu.class);
                }
}
 `